# Problem in download via url. Error 403 forbidden

Tags: download, request

So, I am making a web app to download movies to my google photos where I can input a direct download link and what happens it downloads to server and then upload it to my google photos.

I setup everything from authentication to upload everything was good and working. Fo the final task I used a link

{https://dl1.downahit.com/files/data/Wish_(2023)_HQ_Hindi_Dubbed_Movies_HDRip_Full_HD_720p.mp4}

To download via my web app it gave 403 error. I thought there was problem with headers so I did so.. nothing worked

I even tried --refer.

When I got to the download page{https://www.okhatrimaza.com.ph/download/24341} and click on download button it works but didn't worked via link

Once I tried something it worked and gave a file but it was of 567kb and it was a html file.

My code for downloading

```
def download(url, path, user_agent):
  headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
  response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
  if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
      for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
        f.write(chunk)
    st.success("Download completed successfully.")
  else:
   st.error("Error occurred during download.")

# Custom user agent string
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
```